# How do I change the default arrow icon in the TreeList(KendoReact )?

Tags: reactjs, treelist, kendo-react-ui

I use  KendoReact TreeList https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/treelist/
and I want to change the default arrow icon.How should I do this?

Comment: you mean default arrow icon?

Comment: Yes, exactly...

Comment: Can you check this link https://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-change-expand-collapse-icons-nowadays

Comment: Thanks for your help ... this link was what I wanted  https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-4wlxeb?file=app/main.jsx